# How to run Clojure tests on Windows?

Tags: windows, clojure

I put Clojure in C:\clojure-1.1.0, and start the REPL by:
    java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main

In \test\clojure\test_clojure, there are a bunch of test files.
How to run these?

For example, I tried:
java -cp ......\clojure.jar clojure.main data_structures.clj

And it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Two choices:

1. Once the REPL starts you can manually load the file with:

   (load-file "\data_structures.clj")
2. You can pass a command-line option telling it to load/eval a file upon boot:

   java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i \data_structures.clj -e "(do-stuff)"

Comment: I tried this:
C:\clojure-1.1.0>java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main -i test\clojure\test_clojure\
data_structures.clj -e "(do-stuff)"


The output is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: do-stu
ff in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:4420)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:4366)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:2828)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:4594)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:4405)
...

Comment: Is "do-suff" in the users namespace? If not, you'd need to qualify it or change namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

We use (clojure 1.2):
java -cp "./target/***-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar;src/clojure" jline.ConsoleRunner clojure.main run.clj

I think with tests you can use similar way.